# Conditional argument and return type declarations (aka type hinting)

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

I have the following abstract class which has argument and return type declarations of the `Entity` object.  `Entity` is a fictional placeholder, and in reality they should be declared to show returning `User` (or whatever the actual class which extends `EntityServices` specifies).

Is it possible to have `EntityServices` utilize type declarations of `User` instead of `Entity` without duplicating the script in the `User` class?  If so, how?  If not, is there a workaround that will allow the script to be reused with at least some level of type declaration functionality?

```
<?php
namespace NotionCommotion;
abstract class EntityService
{
    //Constructor in child

    public function get(int $id): ?Entity {
        //Will return User or Bla argument based on the extending class
        return $this->mapper->read($id);
    }

    public function create(array $data): Entity {
        //Will return User or Bla argument based on the extending class
        if (!$this->validator->load($this->getValidationFile())->isValid($data)) throw new UserValidationError($this->validator, $data);
        $this->doTransation(function(){$this->mapper->add($data);});
    }

    public function update(array $data, int $id): Entity {
        //Will return User or Bla argument based on the extending class
        if (!$this->validator->load($this->getValidationFile())->nameValueisValid($data)) throw new UserValidationError($this->validator, $data);
        $this->doTransation(function(){$this->mapper->update($data);});
    }

    public function delete(int $id): void {
        $this->mapper->delete($id);
    }

    public function whatever(Entity $whatever) {
        //Requires User or Bla argument based on the extending class
    }

    protected function doTransation($f){
        try {
            $f();
            $this->pdo->commit();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            throw($e);
        }
    }

    abstract protected function getValidationFile();
}
```

`UserServices` class

```
<?php
namespace NotionCommotion\User;
class UserService extends \EntityService
{
    public function __construct(UserMapper $userMapper, \Validator $validator, Foo $foo) {
        $this->mapper=$userMapper;
        $this->validator=$validator;
        $this->foo=$foo;
    }
}
```

`BlaServices` class

```
<?php
namespace NotionCommotion\Bla;
class BlaService extends \EntityService
{
    public function __construct(BlaMapper $blaMapper, \Validator $validator) {
        $this->mapper=$blaMapper;
        $this->validator=$validator;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Is this possible`? __What__ should be possible?

Comment: Not clear what you want.

Comment: I will edit the original scope to better describe.  Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about [covariance and contravariance](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/object-typehint#variance)?

Comment: @GabrielHeming  I don't think so.  I wish to make the methods in the extended parent abstract class more narrow and match that of the extending child class.

Comment: If I understood what you want, you can't do that in PHP right now. It could be done using generics (Java, C#, etc..) or implementing the method in child classes and using covariance/contravariance.

Comment: You can't do that. Just use interfaces, and declare the return of an interface that `User` should comply with.

Comment: @GabrielHeming  Thanks.  Sounds like you do understand what I am asking.  Implementing every method in `Entity` for every child class which extends `Entity` kind of defeats the benefit of inheritance.

Comment: @yivi  Seems like a good solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in PHP.

Generally, a sane way of doing it would be just using inheritance or interfaces.

E.g, with inheritance:

```
class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}

class Service {
  public function reproduce() : Animal {
    return new Animal();
  }
}


class ImprovedService extends Service {
  public function reproduce() : Animal {
    return new Cat();
  }
}
```

You can't change `reproduce()` definition, but you can return a descendant from the original return definition.

Or with interfaces, something like:

```
interface Mammal {
  public function makeSound() : string;
}

class Dog implements Mammal {
  public function makeSound() : string {
    return "Bark!";
  }
}

class GenericMammal implements Mammal {
  public function makeSound() : string {
    return "???";
  }
}

class Service {
  public function test() : Mammal {
    return new GenericMammal();
  }
}


class ImprovedService extends Service {
  public function test() : Mammal {
    return new Dog();
  }
}
```

Each method has advantages and disadvantages, so it would fall upon you to see which one makes better sense for your case.

Comment: Actually, the interface solution doesn't seem applicable.  It works with `string` because methods in all classes are declared that way.  I was hoping I could leave the declaration off in the parent class, and only include it in the interface, however, this results in error.

Comment: @user1032531 If a class implements an interface, it needs to implement it fully. If you do not want to be be constrained to a return type, just omit it in the interface declaration.

Comment: Yes, I just read the docs: `The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.`  I could omit them in the interface, but then are loosing some of the benefit of an interface.  As others don't see this as an issue, I expect I am not truly understanding how they should be used.

Comment: Still, this is the only way to accomplish what you want. The rest is about properly designing your application. :)